# MongoDB, Studio 3T - Update a filed with Integer32 type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I use **Studio 3T** and I have a field called **state_id**.
When I try to set it to 2 in takes the value of 2.0 (Double) but I need to have  it just 2 of Integer type.

**I execute:**

```
{
    @set : {
        site_id  : null
    }
}
```

and then

```
{
    @set : {
        site_id  : 2
    }
}
```

And this gives me the result: state_id : 2.0
How can I do this?

Comment: Try `{ @set : { site_id : NumberInt(2) } }`

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Veeram.